# inverse kinematic animation alignement of mouvement issue

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have rigged this elephant mesh with inverse kinematic but when I move the leg with the controler bone, the leg bend inward (my goal is to have a leg that bend along the Y axis).

Here are picture to demonstrate:[image]
Here I have moved the leg...
[image]
as you can see the leg moved along the x axis and the knee goes outward
[image]

I think the problem comes from the orientation of the bone or maybe the automatic weightpaint and the pole bone, does anyone know how I can fix this ?

Here is the blender scene [image]

Answer (score 1):

First you can see that if you make an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> the armature is completely messed up in rest pose. So you need to correct all this (if you want pole targets in front of the knees in *Pose* mode by default, put there in front in *Edit* mode as well).

But first to make things cleaner I would align the bones on the axis with some <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Global +X axis*.

[image]

Now select your lowerleg bones in *Bone* mode and in the *IK* constraint set their *Pole Angle* at 0°.

[image]

Now if you want the knee to bend more inwards, you need to move the IK *Pole Target* a bit inwards in *Edit* mode, pole targets are here for this purpose. You can also move the knees a bit inwards. When you'll switch to *Pose* mode it will already work better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As moonboots says I used ctrl + N -> global + x axis (in edit mode), aligne the pole bone withe the bone of the lang and then set the pole angle to 0 in pose mode, but when I move the leg with the IK controler the leg is still bending inward[image]
But I realized that moving the yellow bone with G untill it aligns with the other correct the problem.
[image]
[image]
Even when I go back to rest pose (alt + G) and move again the feet with the IK controler, the leg bend on the desired axis now